# Celery beat sends task regularly, but celery only processes them from time to time in production

Tags: django, celery, django-celery, redis-server

I have a django project with celery integrated using redis.

My celery worker works perfectly in local development, and now I'm deploying in production.
Before daemonizing the process I want to see how celery behaves in the server. The thing is, celery beat sends the tasks correctly every minute (as I scheduled) but the worker seems not to receive it every time. Sometimes it requires 4/5 minutes until the task is received and processed. How is that possible? I have tried debugging, but there is very few information.

see my setup:
settings.py

```
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Europe/Warsaw'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
# Other Celery settings
CELERY_BEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'task-number-one': {
        'task': 'predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='*/1'),
    },
}
```

tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task()
def check_measures():
    print('doing something')
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'config.settings.local')

app = Celery('predict_assistance')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

hereby my logs in production:

```
[2020-03-11 16:09:00,028: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task task-number-one (predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures)
[2020-03-11 16:09:00,038: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures[86f5c999-a53c-44dc-b568-00d924b5da9e]
[2020-03-11 16:09:00,046: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] doing something
[2020-03-11 16:09:00,047: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures[86f5c999-a53c-44dc-b568-00d924b5da9e]: doing something logger
[2020-03-11 16:09:00,204: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures[86f5c999-a53c-44dc-b568-00d924b5da9e] succeeded in 0.16194193065166473s: None
[2020-03-11 16:10:00,049: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task task-number-one (predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures)
[2020-03-11 16:10:00,062: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures[c7786f38-793f-45e6-abb2-1c901e345e8f]
[2020-03-11 16:10:00,072: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] doing something
[2020-03-11 16:10:00,073: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures[c7786f38-793f-45e6-abb2-1c901e345e8f]: doing something logger
[2020-03-11 16:10:00,242: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures[c7786f38-793f-45e6-abb2-1c901e345e8f] succeeded in 0.17491870187222958s: None
[2020-03-11 16:11:00,054: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task task-number-one (predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures)
[2020-03-11 16:12:00,032: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task task-number-one (predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures)
[2020-03-11 16:13:00,035: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task task-number-one (predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures)
[2020-03-11 16:14:00,046: INFO/Beat] Scheduler: Sending due task task-number-one (predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures)
[2020-03-11 16:14:00,053: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures[e0b3ef2b-ba15-421c-9a0f-0ef9f3ebb22a]
[2020-03-11 16:14:00,065: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] doing something
[2020-03-11 16:14:00,066: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures[e0b3ef2b-ba15-421c-9a0f-0ef9f3ebb22a]: doing something logger
[2020-03-11 16:14:00,247: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-3] Task predict_assistance.alerts.tasks.check_measures[e0b3ef2b-ba15-421c-9a0f-0ef9f3ebb22a] succeeded in 0.1897202990949154s: None
```

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance

Comment: At least I would not recommend to use redis as broker backend for celery. Use rabbitmq instead or smth else

Comment: You might try firing up [celery flower](https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to poke around and see if/when the tasks are getting submitted. And to echo the above comment, rabbitmq is going to be more stable than redis as a backend.

Comment: why? redis is worse than rabbitmq?

Comment: alright! I just made the full installation of rabbitmq and seems o work like charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by the comments, the solution was to switch from `redis-server` service to `rabbitmq-server` service